# Spring-Cloud-Stream-Rabbit lead to netty fails to start

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

They can't work together,way ?
In fact, the port is not occupied.Using Netty tcp to connect port 58888 (or change to any other port) it (Netty) is not working. When I don't use SpringCloudStream, netty can start normally.

netty startup error :
"java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind"

--------------------------------Part Maven-----------------------------------

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.7</version>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.75.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

--------------------------------Config-----------------------------------

```
  rabbitmq:
    host: 192.168.31.248
    port: 5672
    username: rabbit
    password: 123456
    virtual-host: /
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        sms-out-0:
          destination: sms-exchange
```

--------------------------------Consumer-----------------------------------

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

@Component
public class SmsConsumer {
    
    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> sms() {
        return System.out::println;
    }
}
```

--------------------------------Producer-----------------------------------

```
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.annotation.Resource;

@Component
public class SmsProducer{
    
    @Resource
    private StreamBridge streamBridge;
    
    public void send(String message) {
        streamBridge.send("sms-out-0" , message);
    }
}
```

Why is no one having this problem, I don't understand why there are no results..............

-----The follow-up is coming, with new progress!!!!!!!!!!!!!

When I removed the Consumer, Netty started normally. It seems that this problem has nothing to do with the port, and I still don't understand the reason.

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

```
@Component
public class SmsConsumer {
    
//    @Bean
//    public Consumer<String> sms() {
//        return System.out::println;
//    }
}
```

When I noticed that the official documentation has tips to avoid confusion made the following changes

```
  rabbitmq:
    host: 192.168.31.248
    port: 5672
    username: rabbit
    password: 123456
    virtual-host: /
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: sms
    stream:
      function:
        autodetect: false
      bindings:
        sms-out-0:
          destination: sms-exchange
```

[Spring Cloud Stream official documentation has tips to avoid confusion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6onbC.png)

But the problem persists and I can't solve it

[netty startup error images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubNps.png)

Comment: May we understand what address are you talking about? Why do you need Netty in the Spring Cloud Stream micorservice though?

Comment: Because of business needs, it is necessary to use netty tcp to connect many devices, but the data reported by the device needs to be sent to other microservices for processing through mq, so I don't understand why "Netty" cannot be used with "RabbitMq( SpringCloudStream way)"

Comment: When they are used together, port occupancy will occur, causing Netty to fail to start, and it is not actually occupied (the port used by Netty), I don't understand why this happens

Comment: Once again, which port are you talking about. Netty and Rabbit binder has no knowledge of one another. They absolutely can work together. What you have is a port conflict and that is what Artem is trying to find out. Which port?

Comment: I'm using Netty tcp connection port 58888, but when I change to any other port, it (Netty) doesn't start properly, when I remove rabbit binder dependency, Netty works fine

Comment: I am not following since rabbit has nothing running on 58888. I am suspecting that this is related to http port (i.e., 8080). Can you specify `server.port` property and set its value to something other then 8080?

Comment: I tried a non-8080 port and it didn't change, but I found the clue, after I commented out the Consumer, Netty worked fine

Comment: May we have some simple project from you to play with and reproduce, please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean, can you clarify?